# Json don't work with an unordered secuence (AngularJS - ui.router)

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS - ui.router App and I working with a remote json.

The forma of the json is the follow:

```
{"data":[
       { "id":0, "name": "Alice","surename": "peterson" }, 
       { "id":1, "name": "Bob","surename": "peterson" },
       { "id":2, "name": "Alirce","surename": "peterson" },
       { "id":3, "name": "Alwicse","surename": "peterson" },
       { "id":10, "name": "Alice","surename": "peterson" }, 
       { "id":12, "name": "Alirce","surename": "peterson" },
       { "id":13, "name": "Alwicse","surename": "peterson" },
       { "id":4, "name": "Awlice","surename": "peterson" },
       { "id":7, "name": "Awlice","surename": "peterson" },
       { "id":6, "name": "Awlice","surename": "Peterson" }
       ]}
```

If I click on a non-correlative number (i.e 10, 12, 13), the app don't show the item detail. But if I click ond a correlative number (0, 1, 2, 3) it works!
You can check the working app on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gMYknVoPRae9HWxfNfB9?p=preview)